# Selection Sort doesn't catch duplicate numbers

Tags: c++, duplicates, selection-sort

What i'm trying to do is implement a simple selection sort algorithm that uses the function minButGreaterThan to find the next smallest number in the array. My problem is if the array has a duplicate number, it gets passed over and left at the end. I've tried changing the controlling if statements to accommodate for this but nothing seems to work. Any advice?

```
    double GradeBook::minButGreaterThan(double x) // - NEEDS TESTING
    {
        double minButGreaterThan = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < classSize; i++)
        {
            if (grades[i] > x)
            {
                minButGreaterThan = grades[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < classSize; i++)
        {
            if (grades[i] > x && grades[i] <= minButGreaterThan)
                minButGreaterThan = grades[i];
        }

        return minButGreaterThan;
    }

void GradeBook::selectionSort() //ascending order -- *DOES NOT WORK WITH DUPLICATE SCORES* - RETEST
{
    double min = absoluteMin();
    for (int i = 0; i < classSize; i++)
    {
        if (grades[i] == min)
        {
            double temp = grades[0];
            grades[0] = grades[i];
            grades[i] = temp;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < classSize-1; i++)
    {
        double next = minButGreaterThan(grades[i]);
        for (int n = 1; n <= classSize; n++)
            if (grades[n] == next)
            {
                double temp = grades[n];
                grades[n] = grades[i+1];
                grades[i+1] = temp;
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: This might be appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Should work with duplicates, a selection sort just takes the minimum and moves it to the left, to the "sorted" portion of the array.

This is my implementation:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using std::swap;
using std::vector;
using std::min_element;

void selectionSort(vector<int> &v) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++) {
        auto minElement = min_element(v.begin() + i, v.end());
        auto minIndex = minElement - v.begin();
        swap(v[i], v[minIndex]);
    }
}
```

You might need to modify it to work with floats. Now, a double floating precision grade (`double`) seems too much. I think a regular `float` is OK.

Comment: Needed it to use the given function minButGreaterThan but thanks for your unhelpful input, i guess...?